# Conversion of Riemann Sum to Integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I was trying to convert a Riemann Sum to an integral however I got the parameters wrong according to the answers from the textbook. Now the Riemann Sum involves a $\ln$ as the function as is as follows:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n {2\over n} \ln ( 1 + {2i\over n})$$

I assumed that the $\operatorname{dx}$ would be equal to $\frac{2}{n}$ so then $\frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{2}{n}$. Then I assumed that $x_i$ would be $1 + 2\frac{i}{n}$ so where $a$ is equal to $1$ and $b$ is equal to $3$ to produce $2$ from the $\frac{2}{n}$. However the answers in my textbooks say that the function is that of $\ln(1+x)$ where the parameters are $b = 2$ and $a = 0$. How do I know which one to use?

Comment: are you sure about the lower bound of $\infty$?

Comment: @Alex, he is wrong, if the lower bound is $\infty$, how can you increment?

Comment: of course he is wrong, it's probably $i=1$

Comment: $a=1, b=3$ are the bounds on the integral

Comment: @alex, you might as well post the answer.

Comment: @alex yeah that's what I mean i=1. I got the same answer as you however the dilemma is that the textbook has the answer as a = 0 and b = 2...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what you have is probably
$$
S=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{n} \log \bigg(1+\frac{2k}{n} \bigg)
$$
here clearly $a=1,b=2+1=3$. Hence you get the integral
$$
S=\int_{1}^{3}\log x dx
$$
EDIT: the integrand can also be $\log(1+x)$, and then the bounds are $a=0, b=2$

Comment: Which is of course equivalent to the answer in the textbook. Looks like OP was on the right track but just didn't realise that part.

Comment: The expression in the question is almost certainly wrong. My solution is based on what I thought he meant, which may not be correct either.

Comment: It is supposed to be i=1 or k=1 whichever convention you want to use. Your answer is the answer that I got, however the textbook says otherwise. Is there another reason to this or is the textbook just simply wrong with that question?

Comment: @user127106: it's the same:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28log%28x%29%2Cx%3D1..3%29, but the function is different, for the solution in the textbook it should be $\log (1+x)$

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much Alex :) I fixed the original post so there's no confusion for future readers.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Ignore this post. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: is it possible that you help me with another question that I'm stuck on?

Comment: post the question, either me or other users may help

Comment: @Phillip you should accept his answer if it helped